# How to define a format function for all namespaces in ClojureScript?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

Since cljs doesnt have a format function, I need to define one myself

if i have a src file with following:

```
(ns formatter
  (:require [goog.string :as gstring]
            [goog.string.format]))

(defn format
  "Formats a string using goog.string.format."
  [fmt & args]
  (apply gstring/format fmt args))
```

how do I make `format` function available in all my src files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably should include the namespace and function in each file where you use it, I don't think any other solution would be a good practice.

```
(ns app.whatever
  (:require [app.utils :only [format]]))
```